# Code::Blocks problema ejecución C+-

Tags: c, ide

Estoy empleando el lenguaje de programación C+- (desarrollado por la UNED) en codeblocks   v 8.02 para programar.

El problema es que a la hora de ejecutar un archivo .cpp este no me lo ejecuta, simplemente dando un mensaje de que falló sin entrar a mayor detalle.

El programa en cuestión es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de un simple print por pantalla.

El problema a la hora de ejecutar es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El nombre de fichero coincide y la ruta también.

Gracias de antemano :)

**NOTA: Si reinstalo el IDE el problema se soluciona momentáneamente.**

Comment: Bienvenido. Sencillamente no podemos ayudarte si no nos dejas información para que podamos conocer el lenguaje y reproducir el problema. Mira como crear un [mre].